# drawing recursively

Tags: java, algorithm

I cannot get this koch snowflake drawing working recursively.

**Recursive method**

```
 public void koch(int n, double size) {
    if (n == 0) {
        t.forward(size);
    } else {

        koch(n - 1, size / 3);   // line 1
        stdTort.rotate(60);            // line 2
        koch(n - 1, size/3);     // line 3
        stdTort.rotate(120);           // line 4
        koch(n - 1, size/3);     // line 5
        stdTort.rotate(60);            // line 6
        koch(n - 1, size/3);     // line 7
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's the tag for the VB (Visual Basic) language. No doubt a quip referencing the fact you've randomly tagged this question with four different programming languages, when it's clearly only using one.

Comment: Well this is a algorithm problem, so every language should be able to solve it right?

Comment: java, The tags has been corrected.

Comment: Shouldn't `t.rotate(120);` be `t.rotate(-120);` ? You want to go left, then right.

Comment: Good effort with the ascii drawing but as someone who's unfamiliar with the Koch snowflake, can you add proper references? I'm not sure the size / 3 is right..

Comment: the size is 300 i have divided that by 3 to get size of 100. so this shouldn't really matter

Comment: Yep sorry should've looked up Koch snowflake before commenting. I think the answers below should mean you're sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your angles are wrong, because they are rotating clockwise where you are expecting them to go anti-clockwise.  In order to get the angle shown in figure 2 you actually need to rotate 120, not 60.  Then to get your final line you want to rotate -60, not 60.

```
    koch(n - 1, size / 3);   // line 1
    t.rotate(120);            // line 2
    koch(n - 1, size/3);     // line 3
    t.rotate(120);           // line 4
    koch(n - 1, size/3);     // line 5
    t.rotate(-60);            // line 6
    koch(n - 1, size/3);     // line 7
```

Thinking about this, I think the reason you are confused is because the rotation doesn't seem to be intuitive.  If your turtle is walking forward to do the first line, then you would expect a rotation to be either clockwise or anti-clockwise from that direction.  But it seems your rotation all starts from the opposite direction.

Expected:

```
        /
-60 = --

+60 = --
        \
```

Actual:

```
-60 = --
       /

       \
+60 = --
```

Comment: if i change line 2 to "-120" i get figure 2, but figure three is still not solved. If i keep 120 for line 4 the drawing doesn't get any slope as shown in figure 3, instead it goes straight.

Comment: @jonny Are you converting degrees to radians before passing them to [Math.sin()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sin(double)) ?

Comment: @jonny What value does direction start with and can you show your rotate method?

Answer (score 0):

If rotate it's anticlockwise, you need  t.rotate(-120);